# Android: Bitmaps loaded from gallery are rotated in ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, gallery

When I load an image from the media gallery into a Bitmap, everything is working fine, except that pictures that were shot with the camera while holding the phone vertically, are rotated so that I always get a horizontal picture even though it appears vertical in the gallery.
Why is that and how can I load it correctly?

Comment: I have the real answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971319/image-orientation-android/32747566#32747566

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Have you looked at the EXIF data of the images? It may know the orientation of the camera when the picture was taken.

Comment: You're right, that was of course the solution. I'm gonna post my code as an example in a separate answer, later, but I mark this one as accepted because it got me on the right track.

Answer (score 192):

So, as an example...

First you need to create an ExifInterface:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filename);
```

You can then grab the orientation of the image:

```
orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
```

Here's what the orientation values mean:
http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html

So, the most important values are 3, 6 and 8.
If the orientation is `ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90` (which is 6), for example, you can rotate the image like this:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

That's just a quick example, though. I'm sure there are other ways of performing the actual rotation. But you will find those on StackOverflow as well.

Comment: Here are all the rotation values for the different orientations: 3: 180, 6: 90, 8: 270

Comment: Don't use magic numbers when you can use named constants: ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180,  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270.

Comment: Watch out of `OutOfMemoryError` when use this approach as you hold two bitmaps in memory at the same time.

Comment: Another complete example... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 70):

Solved it in my case with this code using help of this post:

```
            Bitmap myBitmap = getBitmap(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            try {
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                if (orientation == 6) {
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                }
                else if (orientation == 3) {
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                }
                else if (orientation == 8) {
                    matrix.postRotate(270);
                }
                myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true); // rotating bitmap
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgTakingPic);
            img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Hope it saves someone's time!

Comment: edit suggestions: are there no proper named constants for the orientations 6, 3, 8? could we not skip the new bitmap if no rotation is required?

Comment: As @d60402 previously said in a comment, you can use named constants: ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270.

Comment: @Adrian but "postRotate" expects a degree and ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL is an Int

Answer (score 69):

This is a full solution (found in the Hackbook example from the Facebook SDK). It has the advantage of not needing access to the file itself. This is extremely useful if you are loading an image from the content resolver thingy (e.g. if your app is responding to a share-photo intent).

```
public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
    /* it's on the external media. */
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getInt(0);
}
```

And then you can get a rotated Bitmap as follows. This code also scales down the image (badly unfortunately) to MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION. Otherwise you may run out of memory.

```
public static Bitmap getCorrectlyOrientedImage(Context context, Uri photoUri) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
    BitmapFactory.Options dbo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    dbo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, dbo);
    is.close();

    int rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight;
    int orientation = getOrientation(context, photoUri);

    if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
        rotatedWidth = dbo.outHeight;
        rotatedHeight = dbo.outWidth;
    } else {
        rotatedWidth = dbo.outWidth;
        rotatedHeight = dbo.outHeight;
    }

    Bitmap srcBitmap;
    is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
    if (rotatedWidth > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION || rotatedHeight > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION) {
        float widthRatio = ((float) rotatedWidth) / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
        float heightRatio = ((float) rotatedHeight) / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
        float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);

        // Create the bitmap from file
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = (int) maxRatio;
        srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    } else {
        srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    }
    is.close();

    /*
     * if the orientation is not 0 (or -1, which means we don't know), we
     * have to do a rotation.
     */
    if (orientation > 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(orientation);

        srcBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0, srcBitmap.getWidth(),
                srcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    return srcBitmap;
}
```

Comment: what does that MAX_IMAGE_DIMENDION means?

Comment: It's the maximum width or height of the image you get. I.e. Say you only need a 512x512 image, if you open a 24 megapixel image it is much more efficient to open it already subsampled than to open the whole thing and then scale it down - that would probably exhaust all your memory anyway.

Comment: In my programs I found it useful to define the Bitmap variable in the activity/fragment as private static and setting it to null in the functions. Had less memory troubles then.

Comment: It is smarter to replace MAX_IMAGE_DIMENDION to MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH and MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT

Comment: Saved lots of my time :) Many thanks. For those getting null cursor, you may try `ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(photoUri.getPath());` and then `exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1)` to get orientation (e.g. `ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90`, `ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180`)

Comment: Always returns 0 in Samsung Galaxy S9.

Answer (score 49):

### Use a Utility to do the Heavy Lifting.

[9re](https://gist.github.com/9re) created a simple utility to handle the heavy lifting of dealing with EXIF data and rotating images to their correct orientation.

**You can find the utility code here: https://gist.github.com/9re/1990019**

Simply download this, add it to your project's `src` directory and use `ExifUtil.rotateBitmap()` to get the correct orientation, like so:

```
String imagePath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();             // photoFile is a File class.
Bitmap myBitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

Bitmap orientedBitmap = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(imagePath, myBitmap);
```

Comment: Works for me ! I just resized bitmap to HD format before passing it to ExifUtil.rotateBitmap() to avoid OutOfMemoryError like that :                Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 720, 1280, true);
    photo = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(picturePath, resized);

Comment: @Phil Nice addition. I haven't run into that (I'm using older, shittier Android devices) but that's really good to know.

Comment: you are a hero my friend :)

Comment: @klutch You just made my day. :) To be fair, 9re made wrote the utility code so he's the real hero.

Comment: But just wondering why they need both the imagePath and the original bitmap as arguments, is not just the image path enough :|

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat Great question! I probably knew why this made sense when I was deep into this but right now it seems redundant for me as well. Been spending too much time in React Native perhaps.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat Coming back to this, my guess is that the first argument of `rotateBitmap` is actually where to save the rotated bitmap file to. In our case, we're saving overtop of the existing file so we pass in the `imagePath` for that argument. If you wanted to save a new file (i.e. to not lose the original file), you could provide a different path to save the rotated bitmap to.

Answer (score 12):

Kotlin code:

```
if (file.exists()){
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)

    val exif = ExifInterface(file.absoluteFile.toString())
    val orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL)
    val matrix = Matrix()

    when(orientation){
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> matrix.postRotate(90F)
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> matrix.postRotate(180F)
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> matrix.postRotate(270F)
    }

    val rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0,0 , bitmap.width, bitmap.height, matrix, true)
    bitmap.recycle()
    iv_capture.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap)
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I just wonder why you store the result in a different bitmap instead of assigning it to the same variable. Does it improve performance?

Answer (score 8):

its because gallery correct displaying rotated images but not ImageView
look at here:

```
                    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(),optionss);
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(selectedImagePath);
                    int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                    int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
                    deg = rotationInDegrees;
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    if (rotation != 0f) {
                        matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
                        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    }
```

and you need this:

```
private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {        
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { return 90; } 
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {  return 180; } 
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {  return 270; }            
    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Got it to work after many attempts thanks to a post I can no longer find :-(

Exif seems to work always, the difficulty was to get the filepath. The code I found makes a different between API older than 4.4 and after 4.4. Basically the picture URI for 4.4+ contains "com.android.providers". For this type of URI, the code uses DocumentsContract to get the picture id and then runs a query using the ContentResolver, while for older SDK, the code goes straight to query the URI with the ContentResolver.

Here is the code (sorry I cannot credit who posted it):

```
/**
 * Handles pre V19 uri's
 * @param context
 * @param contentUri
 * @return
 */
public static String getPathForPreV19(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;

    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();

    return res;
}

/**
 * Handles V19 and up uri's
 * @param context
 * @param contentUri
 * @return path
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPathForV19AndUp(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(contentUri);

    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    // where id is equal to
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().
            query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

    String filePath = "";
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }

    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}

public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context,
        Uri contentUri) {
    String uriString = String.valueOf(contentUri);
    boolean goForKitKat= uriString.contains("com.android.providers");

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && goForKitKat) {
            Log.i("KIKAT","YES");
            return getPathForV19AndUp(context, contentUri);
        } else {

            return getPathForPreV19(context, contentUri);
        }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for you. After hours of work with cursors and exifs, this saved may day. As you said, in fact exif has true and reliable data instead of cursor returns. Just give it correct path than it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can just read the path from sd card and do the following code...it'll Replace the existing photo after rotating it..

Not: Exif doesnt work on most of the devices, it gives the wrong data so it's good to hard code the rotating before saving to any degree you want to,You just have to change the angle value in postRotate to any you want to.

```
    String photopath = tempphoto.getPath().toString();
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photopath);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    FileOutputStream fOut;
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(tempphoto);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is to rotate but we don't know if image needs rotation.

Answer (score 2):

I improved upon the answer by Teo Inke. It no longer rotates the image unless it is actually necessary. It is also easier to read, and should run faster.

```
// Load Image
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

// Rotate Image if Needed
try
{
    // Determine Orientation
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

    // Determine Rotation
    int rotation = 0;
    if      (orientation == 6)      rotation = 90;
    else if (orientation == 3)      rotation = 180;
    else if (orientation == 8)      rotation = 270;

    // Rotate Image if Necessary
    if (rotation != 0)
    {
        // Create Matrix
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);

        // Rotate Bitmap
        Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true); 

        // Pretend none of this ever happened!
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = rotated;
        rotated = null;
     }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // TODO: Log Error Messages Here
}

// TODO: Use Result Here
xxx.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need is the real File path
If you have it great, if you are using URI then use this method to
get the real Path:

```
 public static String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI,Context context) {
    String path= contentURI.getPath();
    try {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return path;
    }
    return path;
}
```

extract your Bitmap for example:

```
  try {
                            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);

                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            Log.e("IOException",e.toString());
                        }
```

you can use decodeFile() instead if you wish.

Now that you have the Bitmap and the real Path get the Orientation of the Image:

```
 private static int getExifOrientation(String src) throws IOException {
        int orientation = 1;

        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(src);
        String orientationString=exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
        try {
            orientation = Integer.parseInt(orientationString);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){}

        return orientation;
    }
```

and finally rotate it to the right position like so:

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(String src, Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            int orientation = getExifOrientation(src);

            if (orientation == 1) {
                return bitmap;
            }

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation) {
                case 2:
                    matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    break;
                default:
                    return bitmap;
            }

            try {
                Bitmap oriented = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                bitmap.recycle();
                return oriented;
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

That's it , you now have the bitmap rotated to the right position.

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but probably not the best way to do it, but it might help someone.

```
String imagepath = someUri.getAbsolutePath();
imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
imageview.setImageBitmap(setImage(imagepath, 120, 120));    

public Bitmap setImage(String path, final int targetWidth, final int targetHeight) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
// Get exif orientation     
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
        if (orientation == 6) {
            orientation_val = 90;
        }
        else if (orientation == 3) {
            orientation_val = 180;
        }
        else if (orientation == 8) {
            orientation_val = 270;
        }
    }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

// Adjust extents
            int sourceWidth, sourceHeight;
            if (orientation_val == 90 || orientation_val == 270) {
                sourceWidth = options.outHeight;
                sourceHeight = options.outWidth;
            } else {
                sourceWidth = options.outWidth;
                sourceHeight = options.outHeight;
            }

// Calculate the maximum required scaling ratio if required and load the bitmap
            if (sourceWidth > targetWidth || sourceHeight > targetHeight) {
                float widthRatio = (float)sourceWidth / (float)targetWidth;
                float heightRatio = (float)sourceHeight / (float)targetHeight;
                float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                options.inSampleSize = (int)maxRatio;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
            } else {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            }

// Rotate the bitmap if required
            if (orientation_val > 0) {
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(orientation_val);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            }

// Re-scale the bitmap if necessary
            sourceWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
            sourceHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
            if (sourceWidth != targetWidth || sourceHeight != targetHeight) {
                float widthRatio = (float)sourceWidth / (float)targetWidth;
                float heightRatio = (float)sourceHeight / (float)targetHeight;
                float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);
                sourceWidth = (int)((float)sourceWidth / maxRatio);
                sourceHeight = (int)((float)sourceHeight / maxRatio);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, sourceWidth,     sourceHeight, true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods below scales AND rotates the bitmap according to the orientation:

```
public Bitmap scaleAndRotateImage(String path, int orientation, final int targetWidth, final int targetHeight)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try
    {
        // Check the dimensions of the Image
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Adjust the Width and Height
        int sourceWidth, sourceHeight;
        if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270)
        {
            sourceWidth = options.outHeight;
            sourceHeight = options.outWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            sourceWidth = options.outWidth;
            sourceHeight = options.outHeight;
        }

        // Calculate the maximum required scaling ratio if required and load the bitmap
        if (sourceWidth > targetWidth || sourceHeight > targetHeight)
        {
            float widthRatio = (float)sourceWidth / (float)targetWidth;
            float heightRatio = (float)sourceHeight / (float)targetHeight;
            float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inSampleSize = (int)maxRatio;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        }
        else
        {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        }

        // We need to rotate the bitmap (if required)
        int orientationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(orientation);
        if (orientation > 0)
        {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation != 0f)
            {
                matrix.preRotate(orientationInDegrees);
            };

            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }

        // Re-scale the bitmap if necessary
        sourceWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        sourceHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

        if (sourceWidth != targetWidth || sourceHeight != targetHeight)
        {
            float widthRatio = (float)sourceWidth / (float)targetWidth;
            float heightRatio = (float)sourceHeight / (float)targetHeight;
            float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);
            sourceWidth = (int)((float)sourceWidth / maxRatio);
            sourceHeight = (int)((float)sourceHeight / maxRatio);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.d("Could not rotate the image");
        Logger.d(e.getMessage());
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Example:

```
public void getPictureFromDevice(Uri Uri,ImageView imageView)
{
    try
    {
        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(Uri.getPath());
        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        Bitmap bitmap = scaleAndRotateImage(Uri.getPath(), orientation, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError outOfMemoryError)
    {
        Logger.d(outOfMemoryError.getLocalizedMessage());
        Logger.d("Failed to load image from filePath (out of memory)");
        Logger.d(Uri.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.d("Failed to load image from filePath");
        Logger.d(Uri.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help (rotate 90 degree)(this worked for me)

```
private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap image){
        int width=image.getHeight();
        int height=image.getWidth();

        Bitmap srcBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, image.getConfig());

        for (int y=width-1;y>=0;y--)
            for(int x=0;x<height;x++)
                srcBitmap.setPixel(width-y-1, x,image.getPixel(x, y));
        return srcBitmap;

    }
```

Comment: [Bitmap.createBitmap(…, matrix, …)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean)) is a much faster way to create a rotated bitmap

Answer (score 1):

The cursor should be closed after opening it.

Here is an example.

```
 public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri selectedImage)
{
    int orientation = -1;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() != 1)
       return orientation;

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    orientation = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close(); // ADD THIS LINE
   return orientation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have melted @Timmmm answer and @Manuel. If you do this solution, you will not get a Run Out Of Memory Exception.

This method retrieves the image orientation:

```
private static final int ROTATION_DEGREES = 90;
// This means 512 px
private static final Integer MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION = 512;

public static int getOrientation(Uri photoUri) throws IOException {

    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(photoUri.getPath());
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            orientation = ROTATION_DEGREES;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            orientation = ROTATION_DEGREES * 2;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            orientation = ROTATION_DEGREES * 3;
            break;
        default:
            // Default case, image is not rotated
            orientation = 0;
    }

    return orientation;
}
```

Therefore, you would use this method to resize image before load it on memory. In that way, you will not get a Memory Exception.

```
public static Bitmap getCorrectlyOrientedImage(Context context, Uri photoUri) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
    BitmapFactory.Options dbo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    dbo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, dbo);
    is.close();

    int rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight;
    int orientation = getOrientation(photoUri);

    if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
        rotatedWidth = dbo.outHeight;
        rotatedHeight = dbo.outWidth;
    } else {
        rotatedWidth = dbo.outWidth;
        rotatedHeight = dbo.outHeight;
    }

    Bitmap srcBitmap;
    is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
    if (rotatedWidth > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION || rotatedHeight > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION) {
        float widthRatio = ((float) rotatedWidth) / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
        float heightRatio = ((float) rotatedHeight) / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
        float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);

        // Create the bitmap from file
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = (int) maxRatio;
        srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    } else {
        srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    }
    is.close();

    // if the orientation is not 0, we have to do a rotation.
    if (orientation > 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(orientation);

        srcBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0, srcBitmap.getWidth(),
                srcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    return srcBitmap;
}
```

This works perfectly for me. I hope this helps somebody else

Answer (score 1):

All the previous answers use the [android.media.ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface), which is outdated.

> This class has known issues on some versions of Android. It is recommended to use the AndroidX ExifInterface Library since it offers a superset of the functionality of this class and is more easily updateable.

In newer Android versions (AndroidX), this is how you do it:

```
fun loadBitmapFromFile(file: File): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.path)
    val exif = ExifInterface(file)
    val rotation = exif.rotationDegrees
    if (rotation == 0) return bitmap
    val matrix = Matrix().apply { postRotate(rotation.toFloat()) }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, matrix, true)
}
```

You also have to add `implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.6'` to your build.gradle dependencies.

Make sure you import `androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface` and not the outdated `android.media.ExifInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on the solution above by Timmmm to add some extra scaling at the end to ensure that the image fits within the bounds:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String path, int orientation, final int targetWidth, final int targetHeight) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Adjust extents
        int sourceWidth, sourceHeight;
        if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
            sourceWidth = options.outHeight;
            sourceHeight = options.outWidth;
        } else {
            sourceWidth = options.outWidth;
            sourceHeight = options.outHeight;
        }

        // Calculate the maximum required scaling ratio if required and load the bitmap
        if (sourceWidth > targetWidth || sourceHeight > targetHeight) {
            float widthRatio = (float)sourceWidth / (float)targetWidth;
            float heightRatio = (float)sourceHeight / (float)targetHeight;
            float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inSampleSize = (int)maxRatio;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        } else {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        }

        // Rotate the bitmap if required
        if (orientation > 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(orientation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }

        // Re-scale the bitmap if necessary
        sourceWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        sourceHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        if (sourceWidth != targetWidth || sourceHeight != targetHeight) {
            float widthRatio = (float)sourceWidth / (float)targetWidth;
            float heightRatio = (float)sourceHeight / (float)targetHeight;
            float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);
            sourceWidth = (int)((float)sourceWidth / maxRatio);
            sourceHeight = (int)((float)sourceHeight / maxRatio);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to rotate an image correctly:

```
private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap bitmap, String filePath)
{
    Bitmap resultBitmap = bitmap;

    try
    {
        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(filePath);
        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90)
        {
            matrix.postRotate(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90);
        }
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)
        {
            matrix.postRotate(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180);
        }
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270)
        {
            matrix.postRotate(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270);
        }

        // Rotate the bitmap
        resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.d("Could not rotate the image");
    }
    return resultBitmap;
}
```

Comment: You can merge all the if conditions together to have a smaller code.

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem with the following workaround. Note that I am also scaling the image, which was necessary to avoid OutOfMemoryExceptions.

Beware that this solution will not work properly with portrait images or opside-down images (thank you Timmmm for noting). Timmmm's solution above might be the better choice if that is required and it looks more elegant, too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914291/449918

```
File path = // ... location of your bitmap file
int w = 512; int h = 384; // size that does not lead to OutOfMemoryException on Nexus One
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);


// Hack to determine whether the image is rotated
boolean rotated = b.getWidth() > b.getHeight();

Bitmap resultBmp = null;

// If not rotated, just scale it
if (!rotated) {
    resultBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, w, h, true);
    b.recycle();
    b = null;

// If rotated, scale it by switching width and height and then rotated it
} else {
    Bitmap scaledBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, h, w, true);
    b.recycle();
    b = null;

    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.postRotate(90);
    resultBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBmp, 0, 0, h, w, mat, true);

    // Release image resources
    scaledBmp.recycle();
    scaledBmp = null;
}

// resultBmp now contains the scaled and rotated image
```

Cheers

Comment: This isn't going to work properly. What about portrait images? Upside-down images? Using the exif data is much better.

Comment: It works properly in one of my apps, but of course I have not tested all types of scenarios. @Timmmm could you please be more specific in what scenarios it does not work? I am also quite puzzled about you voting my post down. It seems to be a quite harsh response to an honest try to share a potential solution.

Comment: I didn't mean to be harsh; sorry! I just didn't want anyone to copy your solution hoping it would work. As I said, it won't work for portrait or upside-down images. I will add the correct solution as an answer.

Comment: I see. I will add a comment highlighting your solution above as the prefered one.