# Picture orientation from gallery/camera intent

Tags: android, orientation, image

I'm getting picture to my app from camera / gallery intent. In many phones picture that I read from the intent / Uri is already rotated to correct orientation. For example N1, Legend, Desire that is the case.

But then on some phones ( for example Milestone1, GalaxyS) the picture is always in landscape more no matter which way the picture was taken. This means that in my application portrait picture is presented wrong way to the user. I tried to read EXIF info of the picture but orientation tag is always 0. There has to be a way to find out the right orientation of the picture because in Milestone1 the gallery application shows the portrait pictures correctly.

How do I know if I need to rotate the picture myself before showing it to the user?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Did you get this solved? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: No, I never found a solution for this. I ended up adding a button to UI for manually rotating the image in the cases it doesn't work

Comment: Here's how i've resolved this issue; http://stackoverflow.com/a/8864367/137404

Comment: It Worked for me.. ! Solved Solution
[Solved : How to rotate image to its default orientation selected from gallery in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758952/solved-how-to-rotate-image-to-its-defauld-orientation-selected-from-gallery-in)

Answer (score 25):

Florian answer is working for gallery images.

The following code works for captured images, havn't tried with gallery images but i believe it should work. Hope this helps anybody.

Code :

```
public static int getCameraPhotoOrientation(Context context, Uri imageUri, String imagePath){
     int rotate = 0;
     try {
         context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
         File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
         ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                 imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
         int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                 ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                 ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

         switch (orientation) {
         case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
             rotate = 270;
             break;
         case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
             rotate = 180;
             break;
         case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
             rotate = 90;
             break;
         }


         Log.v(TAG, "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return rotate;
 }
```

**EDIT:**
As can be read in the comments, some devices do not support Exif information, havn't checked which but i think HTC doesn't. be sure to check what devices and create an alternative.

Comment: Which devices you've tried? I've used pretty much exactly the same code but it doesn't work on all devices due to the fact that not all devices include EXIF data to the returned images. Motorola & Samsung devices tend to have the problem.

Comment: I tried it on Samsung Galaxy S1 and it worked.

Comment: Still works on newest Samsung devices, especially 4.3 where this bug still persists. Seems to be fixed in 4.4

Comment: @eric.itzhak what's the purpose of the line "context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);" ?

Comment: not working on htc one m8 (6.0) and Nexus 5x (8.1.1) always return 1

Answer (score 16):

The following method returns the orientation of an image in degrees. It works with images from the gallery. Return values for:

- normal landscape: 0
- normal portrait: 90
- upside-down landscape: 180
- upside-down portrait: 270
- image not found: -1

The code:

```
public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION },
            null, null, null);

    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return cursor.getInt(0);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i get it to work for images that was just captured?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Can you share it if you find a solution?

Comment: Will not work with uri from gallery images. It will return 0 no matter what

Answer (score 3):

```
        int rotate = 0;
        try {
            File imageFile = new File(sourcepath);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                    imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotate);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap , 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: what is bitmap here, that you passed in Bitmap.createBitmap? I just have the source image Uri, not the bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best answer I have found, by ramaral. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20480741/2258389 
Works great for gallery or camera

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: It would have been if I had the reputation

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the gallery object using contentresolver first and then pass the uri created to the image capture intent.  Then you can look at the exif data, NOT the gallery orientation data.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the reply. I'll try if this solves our problem ASAP.

Comment: Right, it turns out I don't really understand what you mean by creating a gallery object using content resolver. Could you please point me to the right place of the API of the object type you mean or to an example code describing the process. Thank you!

Comment: After searching around I found an example of how to do this here: http://geek.gankahhwee.com/2010/11/19/android-invoking-camera-to-take-picturevideo/. Unfortunately, after writing some code using getContentResolver() to create my Uri I still have the same problem of EXIF orientation always being "0".

Answer (score 1):

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

ExifInterface exifReader = new ExifInterface(filePath);

int orientation = exifReader.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);

if (orientation ==ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) {

      // Do nothing. The original image is fine.

} else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {

       matrix.postRotate(90);

} else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {

       matrix.postRotate(180);

} else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {

      matrix.postRotate(270);

}
```

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable

Comment: The point of this question is that the exif information isn't there. With exif data there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with S1, and I noted even if you open the image using stock gallery app it will open in landscape mode(the phone doesn’t know the correct orientation for photo).
And if you rotate the phone to portrait in camera app the icons (take pic, focus and settings) will not rotated, try that in S2 or any device support landscape/portrait camera those icons will be rotated.

What I am sure the stock camera app doesn’t support taking photos in prorate mode.

Answer (score 0):

I already did that for a project, because I had the same problem (Android thinking you'll only do a picture on landscape). What I did was detecting the phone orientation at the time, and then rotate the image. It supposes the orientation is still the same when the intent is received, though.

Comment: This solution isn't really an option for us :( We need to make our app to work every time otherwise the quality won't be acceptable. There must a better way as the gallery application can handle the orientation correctly on both phones.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the same problem that was solved in this question:
[Android: Bitmaps loaded from gallery are rotated in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647993/android-bitmaps-loaded-from-gallery-are-rotated-in-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way!

```
private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
        return 90;
    } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
        return 180;
    } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        return 270;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And in the code,

```
Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualImage, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

Simple!

Comment: what is `actualImage` here? I just have the source image Uri, not the bitmap

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing : 
first check the orientation of image taken by camera using its meta data information , and If we found this in portrait then we have to rotate the image by 90 and display otherwise only display.

For getting the Information about orientation of image we can use Exif interface.
That's It!

Answer (score 0):

The simple exiftodegree answers only consistently work when you have taken a photo and i use it for such. For those of you experiencing issues with choosing a photo and getting the correct orientation, see my answer here: [Image Orientation - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971319/image-orientation-android/32747566#32747566)