# How to know if picture is landscape or portrait?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have pictures in my Gallery that are both landscape or portrait. The show up correctly in the Gallery application.   When I use an intent to select the picture from the gallery I get a URI back.  But before I display the picture how do I know if the picture is portrait or landscape?

My application selects pictures using an Intent like this:

```
    private OnClickListener btnChooseFromLibraryListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
    }
};
```

Here is how I get the intent back:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            SetPicture(filePath);
        }
    }
}

private void SetPicture(String filePath) {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    Log.d("TW", "Picture Path:" + filePath);
    String size = String.format("Width:%d Height:%d", bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
    Log.d("TW", size);
    ivPicture.setImageBitmap(bm);
    ui.setLastPicture(filePath);        
}
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4517634/420015)

Answer (score 6):

Use this inside `onActivityResult()`

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
                    Cursor cur = managedQuery(selectedImage, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
                    int orientation = -1;
                    if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
                        orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
                    }
```

And use Matrix object to rotate your images

```
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  matrix.postRotate(orientation);
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a `MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION` field used by the content provider.

The code would need to be slightly modified by including the field to tell you what [orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html#ORIENTATION) the image is at which is expressed in degrees, 0, 90, 180, 270.

```
String[] filePathColumn = {
         MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, 
         MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION
};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, 
                   filePathColumn, 
                   null, 
                   null, 
                   null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
int orientationIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathPathColumn[1]);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
String degreesOrientation = cursor.getString(orientationIndex);
cursor.close();
// Now degreesOrientation will tell you exactly the rotation, as in
int nDegrees = Integer.parse(degreesOrientation);
// Check nDegrees - for example: if (nDegrees == 0 || nDegrees == 180) portrait.
```

Answer (score 1):

After the above "Answers" I wrote the following method.  Hopefully this will help someone else.

```
private int GetRotateAngle(Uri imageUri) {
    String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, columns, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { return 0; }
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int orientationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[1]);
    int orientation = cursor.getInt(orientationColumnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    return orientation;
}
```