# Detecting orientation of images in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-orientation

I am hitting a server and getting images which I will show up in gallery. Before that I want to get the orientation of the images so that if the images are in landscape mode so I can convert those in portrait.
 I am able to rotate is using matrix but I am not able to get the orientation. 
I tried using ExifInterface but that requires path where image is stored.
I tried a demo with images in drawables. But when I do

```
orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
```

But is is always giving value as 0. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could just compare the image height and width? (i.e. width > height = landscape, width < height = portrait).

Answer (score 1):

Some devices doesn't support the Exif information feature. You can see an example of how to implement and a longer discussion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11084765/969325).