# How can I set the orientation of images in a gridview (taken with the phone camera)?

Tags: android, imageview, photo, photos, photo-gallery

I'm working on a college assignment for an app that will allow me to tag photos with my phone contacts. 
I'm using a GridView of ImageViews to display the thumbnails, that works fine. However, all the images are displayed in landscape, irrespective of which way they were taken with the camera. 
I've looked at the ImageView methods, but I can't see anything that tells me what the original orientation was when the photo was taken. Is it perhaps in ImageView.getDrawableState()?

The Gallery app on the phone opens the images in the correct orientation, so I figure I'm missing a readable attribute of the photo somewhere?

Comment: I can't really help you but I can tell you that ImageView neither has a method to get properties of the pic nor one to change the orientation of the pic. I'd have a look at the Bitmap class, but that's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the Bitmap class. There must be a tag somewhere though, the gallery knows which way the photos were taken.

Comment: Perhaps this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517634/picture-orientation-from-gallery-camera-intent