# How does the JPEG orientation feature work?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, jpeg, android-imageview

I do have some images ([example](http://i.kb.irrelevant.at/279939a61eec6fb0e51e434c1c6c5a6f.jpg)) which will be displayed differently depending on the software I am using.

When I open the image in my browser, the picture loads from the right side to the left ([in contrast to other images which are loading from top to bottom](http://i.kb.irrelevant.at/305d16d2a5788fe2010ec7cd7b0fdf5c.jpg)).

**Browser:**
[image: Image Browser]

When I display the same image in an Android Application (via `UrlImageViewHelper`) the image will be displayed with an rotation of 90°.

**Android:**
[image: Image Android]

'Normal' Images (that are loading from the top downwards) are being displayed correctly in my application.

**Questions**

1. Where does the browser get the information about the orientation of the image?
2. How could I implement an Android ImageView that is aware of the original orientation of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Put the rotated jpeg in your res/drawable. Set an ImageView to use that. See what happens.

UrlImageViewHelper doesn't actually do special image loading. It just uses the BitmapFactory like it should.

This is very likely to be an Android framework/libjpeg bug where jpeg rotation EXIF tag is not being honored.

Comment: You're right. Loading the image from a Resource has the same output, this is an Android issue. Thank you for your help and your awesome work!

Comment: This seems to be the solution: "Android: How to read the exif-orientation tag": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647993/android-bitmaps-loaded-from-gallery-are-rotated-in-imageview