# Android: fast image slider with *correctly rotated* images

Tags: android, image, imageview, image-rotation

There are a lot of examples how to use ViewPager as an image slider, but I haven't seen any that handle the problem of ***correctly rotated*** images:

Now actually I have a solution for this, but the problem is that the image sliding is *painfully slow* when the image size is over about 3000*1500 pixel because of **the extra rotation step:**

The ImageView itself doesn't care about the correct orientation when setting an image via
setImageURI or setImageBitmap.

This means you first have to find out the  [correct orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647993/android-bitmaps-loaded-from-gallery-are-rotated-in-imageview) yourself and then eventually do a

```
matrix.postRotate(rotation)
```

and create a new bitmap using

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0, srcBitmap.getWidth(),
                srcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

This additional bitmap creation really slows it down.

If the was a method to load an image "rotated on the fly" ?  Sth. like BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream,matrix) ?

I have also tried to increase the ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit value to 3, but with 
the result of "java.lang.OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget" errors.

Somehow it must be possible because with the default "Gallery" app the sliding is really fast even with very large images...But I guess this not a trivial task ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10104318/1321873

Comment: Thanks,also i have found in the meantime that the BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize could be the key: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html --> passing the ImagesView's width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution: to get a responsive, fast & fluid image sliding behaviour two things need to be done:

1. Do the bitmap loading in the background using AsyncTask
   https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html
2. Load a downsampled version of the bitmap using BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize  (calculated using the ratio between ViewPager's and the Bitmap's dimensions)

   https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html