# Android bitmap drawed incorrectly either from canvas or from BitmapFactory.createBitmap(src,x,y,w,h)

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap

On Android, i'm trying to crop an image bitmap taken from camera to a fixed width / width which is smaller than the original photo taken, but when I create the cropped image the result always gets rotated (even if no matrix is defined) see https://i.stack.imgur.com/9okuX.jpg
as original and https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kues.jpg as the cropped Image, which is being rotated and shows up incorrectly.

Why does the createBitmap method rotates the bitmap to be drawn in the destination bitmap.

Relevant code as follows

```
try {       int dstWidth = params[0].intValue();
            int dstHeight = params[1].intValue();
            int targetSize = Math.min(dstWidth, dstHeight);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mPhotoUri), null, options); 
//calculate min inSampleSize for avoiding memory problems
            options.inSampleSize = calculateImageInSampleSize(options, targetSize, targetSize);
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap originalPhotoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(mPhotoUri), null, options);
            mOriginalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalPhotoBitmap, originalPhotoBitmap.getWidth() - targetSize,
                                                        originalPhotoBitmap.getHeight() - targetSize, targetSize, targetSize);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//codefor inSampleSize calculation from http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

private int calculateImageInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options originalSize, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) {
    final int width = originalSize.outWidth;
    final int height = originalSize.outHeight;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > targetHeight || width > targetWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = height /2;
        final int halfWidth = width /2;

        while ((halfHeight /inSampleSize) > targetHeight &&
                (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > targetWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647993/android-bitmaps-loaded-from-gallery-are-rotated-in-imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every device followed different orientation in camera so you followed this example solve your problem

```
private Bitmap imageRotating(String filePath){
    try{
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        return rotateBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(filePath,150,224), orientation);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {

    try{
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
        try {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but ExifOrientation always returned 0 Undefined so no rotation was applied, i became with a much more simpler solution by decoding with BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeOptions to check for outWidth>outHeight, then is landscape and required rotation, simpler approach but it worked, anyway @Thirumoorthy Moorthy 's answer pointed me in the right way, so i accept your answer