# Gallery images get rotated when saved

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, image-rotation

I have been trying to save images to `Firebase Storage` but I noticed that almost all pictures saved from Gallery/Google Drive get rotated.(usually by 90 degrees)

Reading through older posts I realized that this is a common issue and I tried solving it by trying either solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925712/android-getting-an-image-from-gallery-comes-rotated) , or from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726860/android-how-to-detect-the-image-orientation-portrait-or-landscape-picked-fro) , this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a) and I could go on.

After roughly 8 hours I finally decided to ask here. **Is there a better and easier implementation to stop the images from getting rotated?**

My last (and unsuccessful, obviously) implementation using `ExifInterface` (which returns all the time 0) is this one:
**Selecting picture**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

**OnActivityResult**

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        int rotateImageAngle = getPhotoOrientation(getContext(), selectedImage, filePath);

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
            addPictureButton.setText("Done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if( bitmap != null)
        {
            RotateBitmap(bitmap , rotateImageAngle);
        }
    }
```

**Helper methods**

```
 public int getPhotoOrientation(Context context, Uri imageUri, String imagePath){
    int rotate = 0;
    try {
        context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
        File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
        }

        Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
        Log.i("RotateImage", "Rotate value: " + rotate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rotate;
}
public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, int angle)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Note: If needed I will add the code that uploads images to Firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to a solution thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925712/android-getting-an-image-from-gallery-comes-rotated).

I am going to post below a modified working version of the code for anybody that has this issue.

**Fire up picture selection from gallery**

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

**OnActivityResult checking original roatation of the selected picture**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {

        // Get selected gallery image
        Uri selectedPicture = data.getData();
        // Get and resize profile image
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        // TRY getactvity() as well if not work
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(selectedPicture, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        loadedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            File pictureFile = new File(picturePath);
            exif = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;

        if (exif != null)
            orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                loadedBitmap = rotateBitmap(loadedBitmap, 90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                loadedBitmap = rotateBitmap(loadedBitmap, 180);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                loadedBitmap = rotateBitmap(loadedBitmap, 270);
                break;
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(loadedBitmap);
    }
}
```

**RotateBitmap method**

```
    public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int degrees) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degrees);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```