# How to set the orientation of bitmap image

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview

In my app I have an image view. The user select the image from the gallery and set it on the image view. But whenever the user select camera pic from the gallery, the camera pic gets rotated 90 degrees always. Here's my code below.

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";

    ImageView imageView;
    EditText number, name;
    Button setTimeButton;
    ImageButton imageButton;
    TimePickerDialog timePicker;
    long selectedTimeInMillis;
    String enteredName, enteredNumber;

    private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 100;

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PI = 1001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        setTimeButton = findViewById(R.id.set_time);
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.place_call_button);

        number = findViewById(R.id.number);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, SELECT_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        setTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                        selectedTimeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                        if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                            hourOfDay = hourOfDay - 12;
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, hourOfDay + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Selected time in millis:" + selectedTimeInMillis);
                    }
                }, hour, minute, false);
                timePicker.show();
            }
        });

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enteredName = name.getText().toString().trim();
                enteredNumber = number.getText().toString().trim();
                if (enteredNumber.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter  a number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
                intent.putExtra("FAKE_NAME", enteredName);
                intent.putExtra("FAKE_NUMBER", enteredNumber);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE_PI, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, selectedTimeInMillis, pendingIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your call has been placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.quick_call:
                quickCall();
                return true;

                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = null;
                if (imageUri != null) {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                }
                Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked any Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void quickCall(){

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        long millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        Intent quickCallIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
        quickCallIntent.putExtra("QUICK_FAKE_NAME", "Shanks");
        quickCallIntent.putExtra("QUICK_FAKE_NUMBER", "+91 98554 34734");
        PendingIntent quickCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE_PI, quickCallIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis + 10000, quickCallPendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your call has been placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to fix this ?

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mani.fakecall.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:shape="oval"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:cardCornerRadius="48dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc_select_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/display_number"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/display_name"
            android:inputType="textCapWords" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/set_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/set_time"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/place_call_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_fake_call_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_button"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/color_place_call_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_call_white_24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android getting an image from gallery comes rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925712/android-getting-an-image-from-gallery-comes-rotated)

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem

Comment: show xml of imageview

Comment: I have uploaded the xml file also