# Rotated images on Android

Tags: android, firebase

When I take camera images from a gallery, the images are rotated. I've read thousands of tutorials about this and how to fix it, but I'm still confused (I'm a bad programmer and beginner). I understand that to solve the problem I need to use an `Exif` class, but...

First, in `onActivityResult`, when I get `URL selectedImage = data.getData()`, how do I get the Path of this? Should I use Path or Name of image, and how do I get the path or name? Now, I understand `Exif` works with files, not bitmaps? And I must make File, and file search the path of an image: so, after I get the URL `selectedImage`, how do I make that file use `exif`? How can I get the path of the URI?

Excuse my enormous ignorance; if anyone can help me I'll be grateful!

Comment: Here are some good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647993/android-bitmaps-loaded-from-gallery-are-rotated-in-imageview

Comment: thanx man,I found the answer there