# captures camera picture rotates on some android devices

Tags: java, android, image, camera

On some devices (Nexus 9, Nexus S, ...) the camera loads a rotated picture in `ImageView`. I've tried to fix that with **ExifInterface** but no success. Does anybody have an idea on this code sample?

compiled SDK version is 25
min SDK version is 15

```
public void capturePhoto(String targetFilename) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I encountered the same issue long back, where some devices, (Samsung and Lenovo) had orientation issues, where code worked perfectly on rest of the devices, What i did was to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), to place image on image view, even tried with picasso and universal image loader, But somehow Glide worked

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914291

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a

Answer (score 0):

use following code:

```
@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
int rotation = getPhotoRotation();
        rotatePicture(rotation, data);
        savePicture();
        setSafeToTakePhoto(true);
    }
```

get rotation of device from here:

```
private int getPhotoRotation() {
        int rotation;
        int orientation = mOrientationListener.getRememberedNormalOrientation();
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraID, info);

        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
        } else {
            rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
        }

        return rotation;
    }
     private int getRememberedNormalOrientation() {
            rememberOrientation();
            return mRememberedNormalOrientation;
        }
     private void rememberOrientation() {
            mRememberedNormalOrientation = mCurrentNormalizedOrientation;
        }
```

Use above code to detect mobile orientation and save image as per device rotaion if you dont want to recognize mobile rotation set   int orientation = your rotation;