# Wrong Exif orientation tag in Xiaomi

Tags: android, rotation, exif

I'm using `ExifInterface` for rotationg image picked from gallery by detecting orientation tag, and it's working. Recently I tested app on Xiaomi Mi 9 SE and found out that photo took from camera has orientation tag 8 (rotate 270) but the photo orientation is correct and doesn't require rotationg. Why orientation tag is wrong? How can i find correct orientation for rotating?

Comment: I face the same problem on Xiamo Mi. The EXIF tag says it needs 90° rotation, but it is already in correct orientation. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MaxPower Unfortunately not yet.

Comment: The same problem on Xiaomi Mi8 Android 10 for a photo just taken by the camera. EXIF orientation is 6 (ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 - "the image is rotated by 90 degree clockwise"). Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: See solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647993/android-bitmaps-loaded-from-gallery-are-rotated-in-imageview

Comment: This is a device bug.

Comment: @Gregory Which answer were you referring to? The top one only solves the case where the Exif was tagged correctly. I wrote both camera and image loading for review and made sure they followed the recommended practices yet still have issues only on some Xiaomi devices.