# Image from Google Drive Android Studio API gets rotated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am using the Java Google Drive API in Android Studio to download an image from the drive:

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(mContext.getFilesDir() + "/" + destPath); 
mDriveService.files().get(id).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Most images get saved normally on the device (like the original on drive). But some images get saved rotated.

What I mean is, for example, I have a photo on google drive which is orientated in portrait mode. But after the code above downloads it on the device, the photo on the device is in landscape mode.

Comment: How about file size (in bytes) of original and copy?

Comment: `the photo on the device is in landscape mode.` Where do you see it displayed? By which app?

Comment: Apparently the downloaded image is not rotated when downloaded, but it gets rotated while doing this:
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmpImgFile.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem was actually not saving the image, but the way I was looking at the image (because I was displaying it in an ImageView as a Bitmap).
While doing decodeFile, the image was getting rotated.

For that, the solution I used is here:
[Android: Bitmaps loaded from gallery are rotated in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647993/android-bitmaps-loaded-from-gallery-are-rotated-in-imageview)